# "the trait `SupportsReturningClause` is not implemented for `Sqlite`"

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to get the diesel crate to work with SQLite but going off the getting started guide, it does not seem to work for sqlite.

The code which does work with postgres but not sqlite

```
  diesel::insert_into(schema::subscriptions::table)
      .values(&new_subscription)
      .get_result(&connection)
      .expect("Error saving new subscription")
```

The error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Sqlite: SupportsReturningClause` is not satisfied
  --> src/responder.rs:41:12
   |
41 |           .get_result(&connection)
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `SupportsReturningClause` is not implemented for `Sqlite`
```

I can see some references in [the documentation](https://diesel.rs/guides/all-about-inserts.html) about returning clause for diesel but I'm not entirely sure what I should change this to for it to work.

Comment: As the linked documentation states the sqlite backend does not support the RETURNING clauses. You may have to replace `get_results` with `execute` to execute the INSERT and then issue an query to retrieve the inserted records.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the solution

Comment: Have you looked at the [SQLite version](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/tree/v1.4.8/examples/sqlite) of the example code?

Comment: Yeah I had found that solution. Figured it was still useful to make a post for others since the exact error message doesn't really show up on google (This post is the second result when searching now).

Comment: @Qwertie , it was indeed useful for me, and I think will be for others :), maybe you could add an answer to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `execute` rather than `get_results` works for SQLite. This will not return the result of the query though so a second query will have to be run to get the updated values.

Comment: thank you. 
it is not obviouse that PG method not word for SQLite.

Comment: I know this question is a year old now, but for sqlite, after the insert you can use `select last_insert_rowid()`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/all-about-inserts.html#the-returning-clause):

> On the SQLite backend, support for the RETURNING clause can be enabled with a feature flag, returning_clauses_for_sqlite_3_35.

Indeed, it works for me with Diesel 2.1.1 and SQLite 3.39.5:

```ini
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "2.1.1", features = ["sqlite", "returning_clauses_for_sqlite_3_35"] }
```